Is there a safe way to walk a dog while riding a bicycle?
You know those dogs that are so well trained that they walk beside their person with a slack leash ignoring other dogs and squirrels and rabbits?
That's not my dog.
She likes to trot rather than walk so if I ride a bike at a leisurely pace she should be able to happily trot along.
She isn't horrible on a leash but she is far from perfect. She will try to go after dogs, squirrels and rabbits. I'm afraid we'll be trotting along, she'll see a rabbit, go after the rabbit and pull me off the bike.
Any suggestions for the best way to safely walk a dog while riding a bike?


I'm no dog owner, but this might interest you (I coincidentally saw it a few minutes ago) Wales goes for world sporting glory in dog-powered bike race

Train your dog, if it is strong enough to pull you from the bike it will also be strong enough to pull the bike over with you on it if attached to the bike instead.

Ride a 3- or 4-wheeled recumbent that can't tip over?

@ChrisH They use a bungee cord. Maybe that would work for me.

How urban/ rural is your area? Maybe it is easiest to just not leash the dog at all and just stop the bike whenever she runs off into the forest.

@quarague I live in a standard U.S. suburb. Leash laws and everything. Even then, the thought of having to find her in the forest seems less than optimal.

@Erlkoenig My wife has an adult Big Wheel - a low slung trike - that can't be pulled over and that is safe. But, it's not designed for longer rides. A half mile is a long ways for that trike.

Walk the dog on foot, but make her pull a weighted cart.

A friend of a friend was walking his dog on a leash while riding a bicycle. The dog went around a mailbox, the leash caught and the cyclist went down. He suffered brain damage that has taken years to recover from, and he is still not back to normal. Just an anecdote, but ... I would be very wary of this.

I don't have enough reputation to post an answer. Here's a product that you can mount on your bike to attach the dog leash: https://www.amazon.com/Springer-Dog-Exerciser-Biking-your/dp/B0017NM4OE
Never tried it myself, but it looks like safety is well considered.

Leash to steering column; long fishing rod; sausage. Poor man's e-bike.

There is no "safe" way to ride a bike with a bonkers dog, so just don't.   You could put the dog in a trailer or if the dog is small then in a front-basket.  But that's not exercising.
I have a macklemore scooter and sometimes walk the dog from that.  I have the 1.5m leash in my left hand and steer with the right hand.
He will stop suddenly but we're normally doing 6-8 km/h so I can step off and stop quickly.   It also pays to be alert and anticipate whatever's coming up.  If there are other dogs nearby, I just walk for a bit.
Do also consider the safety of your dog.  Getting a paw or snout or tail caught in the spokes or chain or pedal could cause a significant injury.

This may be the best answer. Just don't do it.

Having once had TWO bonkers dogs that I had the bright idea to get the energy out of them by running them while I was on the bike I can thoroughly approve of this answer.  They jerked me off my bike in the first block and then ran off.  While I was trying to clean up my cuts a neighbor rang the bell to tell me my dogs were running lose (with their leases behind them) and I'm pointing to the blood on my face like "yeah! how do you think this happened?"

Also consider the safety of other people.  Like anyone who could get injured If the dog does something crazy.  Like anyone on the jury when you're defending yourself because your dog did something crazy, listening to your explanation of why you thought having a big dog attached to your bike when you ride was safe enough to ride anywhere near someone else...

I've seen someone doing this and I would be worried about the leash getting wrapped around one of the wheels which could be bad for both the dog and rider.  Your first sentence made me imagine some sort of tandem solution, though.  Maybe a caged treadmill on the back.

@JimmyJames a basket on the front works well for small dogs, they get fresh air without getting tired.  But its not the exercise a husky needs.

There are bikes and trailers suitable to transport big dogs, still no exercise for the dog.

@AndrewHenle it's bad enough when people on foot walk dogs on shared paths or country lanes using long road-coloured leads.  Dogs often choose to go the wrong side of other path users

@ChrisH What really bothers me about that is when people do that with small dogs.  Do they have any idea what will happen to a small dog that gets run over by a narrow-tired road bike?  I ran over a rabbit once at 20+ mph/30+ kph when it was startled out of some trailside brush and ran right under my wheels.  KKK-KKRUNCH! and it was NOT pretty.

@AndrewHenle I've seen the same happen to a squirrel. Within a couple of weeks earlier this year I got knocked over by a medium dog while running, and saw a friend stop just in time for a dog to hit their front wheel side-on, hard enough to knock it out of the dropout.  Just recently I was going fairly quickly on a country road fairly early in daylight, a couple on one side, dog on the other.  I would have gone full tilt into the lead if it hadn't come out from the bushes.

@Willeke I have visions of a Flintstones-style car, but a bike trailer, with the dog harnessed inside but its feet on the ground

The safest way to walk a dog with a bike is off leash. With a well trained dog, on the right bike trail, it can be done safely.  Your dog is not ready, and being a Husky (or is it Malamute - I can't tell the difference), may never get there.  Trail counts - there are plenty of social media videos of well-trained dogs being harassed by other less well-trained dogs. No matter how well trained and behaved your dog is, it can still be attacked (although that would happen on lead anyway).
For off leash, your dog needs really good basic skills that a bomb proof before its safe. Loose lead walking (it is the core for the rest), Leave - especially if it has a high prey drive, Close, Recall and an emergency Stop (or Drop). This takes time and dedication - you have to decide if you are prepared to put the effort in.  You need to become good at reading your dogs body language and paying attention. If you fail head off the instinct to chase prey, your job become exponentially difficult.
For on leash, you obviously need the loose leash walking, but it needs to be better. When walking, a lead in hand gives you instant access to a short tug to bring attention focus back to you (e.g. dog sees a squirrel). When on a bike, you do not have this luxury. A momentary hesitation here can lead to loss of dog's focus - onto something more interesting.
Really the question is about dog obedience, more suited to other Q/A sites than this one. If you want to take it in a different direction, and harness your dogs natural/instinctive pulling desire (if she has it), you could look at Bikejoring.

I'm confused. The question is how to walk a dog with a leash on a bike. It sounds like you are recommending off leash.

Can you edit this a bit more? I'm having trouble parsing some of the sentences, enough that I don't think I understand what you mean.

While I have "walked" my various dogs on bike at various times in my life, I don't really recommend it. I've tried various ways of attaching leashes and harnesses, also some outrigger devices that keep the dog behind you (which the "dog whisperer" says is better for their behavior). I never really had problems with the dogs bounding after squirrels or anything while we are moving - the only comparable incident happened while I was stopped and talking to somebody.  But for me the question was "what is the worst that could happen?"  The dog could pull you off your bike, or the dog might suddenly stop when you don't, e.g. if the dog is scared of something, like a bridge that makes a funny noise when you cross, or which has a grating that allows the dog to see the rocks below. Somebody could get hurt.
I'll go on to talk about what you can do, but it does take us a bit out of scope for bicycles.
First, amusing but not very serious aside: I also used to walk my dog on rollerblades. Actually, two dogs - whereas I only ever walked one dog at a time on bicycle.  My biggest advice here would be to make sure that you have a proper stopping system. At first I used heel brakes on the rollerblades, but took the brakes off to play hockey, and forgot the next time I took my two dogs for a walk. I distinctly remember one of my dogs looking back over her shoulder at me as we went faster and faster, exceeding My breaking skills at that time. Fortunately I could deliberately wipe out onto a grassy lawn.
On a more serious but still not bicycle note: I used to have a pair of huskies. Huskies want to run! Huskies want to pull!
You might want to look into "dry land mushing" - how dogsledders train when there is not snow on the ground. Typically they use scooters or kick bikes that are sturdier than otherwise. Plenty of companies eager to sell their wares to you.  But there are also people doing it on bicycle: dry land ski joring or bike joring.
Look around: there are many videos, but more importantly there may be a local club that may give you advice, and perhaps more importantly may have some training courses. I just realized that "training courses" has two appropriate meanings: classes, but also routes or trails that are known to be good for practicing dryland mushing, eg with not so many ordinary non-mushers around, and not so many steep hills or dangerous curves.
But: many of the disclaimers on webpages with videos emphasize that dryland mushing, and bike-joring in particular can easily lead to serious injury.
As for myself: walking, trotting, running dog(s) on a kick bike scooter felt much safer than from a bicycle. You're much closer to the ground, much less likely to go over the top, it's much easier to  slow them down.  Kick bike felt easier than rollerblades, at least until I became confident in my skating skills - you can't pop out of your blades and run/drag to slow the dogs down the way you can from a scooter. Both feel safer than biking with dogs, and I have been biking with dogs for decades, since I was a kid, but only tried dryland mushing and rollerblades with dogs when I was an adult.
Huskies need to run! Huskies need to pull! :-(
Unfortunately, huskies also need to shed...

If the dog runs all over the place then dry land mushing may not get you very far.  And if the dog can be trained to be disciplined enough for dry land mushing, it can probably be trained to run next to a bike and stay there...

Huskies do shed! Twice a year a major fur drop and then continuously all year. I'm not sure what your suggestion is. I'm looking for the best way to walk a dog on a leash (of some kind) on a bicycle. Maybe the answer is "Don't"

Jess (40 lbs mixed-breed) used to absolutely love to run.  But the fun of chasing cats, squirrels, etc. was too much for her, and off she'd shoot!
I got a collar where the lead went around her nose (a "halty"?): instant slowdown!  But I was still worried about the bike being pulled over.
I took my end of the long lead, wrapped it couple of times around the "headstock" of the bike, and then led it over to a handgrip where I could easily hold it from getting away.  Should an unexpected yank arrive at my hand, I could judge how serious it was. Then if necessary, I could quickly release it without tipping the bike over.
It didn't take long before she and I worked it out, so smooth traveling was attained.
As she matured, the leash was no longer required.  If I wasn't going fast enough, she'd turn around and bark at me!   ("Faster there, slowpoke!")

I like the Halty idea - I've seen those around. I can't just let go of the leash and let her chase a rabbit into the street and in front of a car.

disclaimer 1: I have never owned a dog(but have ridden 10 km with a 10 kg box in hand several times)
disclaimer 2: this is not really an answer but rather criticism of some on the comments
Never tie anything that swings around to your bike frame. Even a 2kg bag can pull hard in an unexpected direction in the wrong time.
Much more never tie anything to the handlebars - middle or ends, doesn't matter.
What I would do: grasp the leash in the rear brake hand and then do some compromise between also holding the grips or just resting the fist on it. See how it goes. The idea is to be able to release the leash in 100ms. Obviously what happens to the dog from then on is not considered.

It is possible to tie things to a bike frame safely. Panniers are one example. I'm not sure it's possible to tie a dog to a frame safely but I haven't ruled it out yet. Releasing the leash is not an option.

suggest "never tie anything loosely to the frame" because panniers are well secured, whereas a dog isn't.

@DavidD and Criggie: thanks for the correction guys - better? Should have just edited in! My confusion stems from my first ever problems with hanging a bag from the handlebars - all the fruit inside would get sucked by the spokes and crushed against the fork's leg, leading to sudden deceleration. Let me nitpick at Criggie a bit: try carrying a lead ball inside empty panniers ;-p.

fair point - panniers by themselves can be floppy.  Part of the "system" depends on the shape of the frame where they rest on.

@Vorac a bag hanging on the bars is doable but depends heavily on the bag and the fill.  Two bags, balanced, is better.  But I'd never plan on doing that - I've got plentiful bike luggage and backpacks.  Bags hung off the bars are for unplanned carrying (e.g. delays mean not having time to go home and drop off stuff before the shops shut, so stopping off while already laden)

No idea how well that works (I don't have a dog), but I regularly see people (in the city and on the outskirts) with these:
https://www.amazon.com/Unicam-Retractable-Exercise-Essentials-Installation/dp/B08C9QVYCD/
(first random search result).

How does this control the dog and keep the bike upright when the dog goes full speed away from the bike?

Do you have any experience of this ?  Positives and negatives both are worth adding.

I would also appreciate at least a short, in-post description of what "these" are, lest the link break later. As it stands, I don't even know what you searched for to get that "first random result." Thanks for contributing!
